# how to generate storage account SAS token through curl

Tags: azure, curl

I need to generate a SAS token for blob container using curl command. Can someone guide me on how do i do that

i tried

```
curl -X PUT -T LICENSE.TXT --user client id of sp:client secret of sp https://axxx.blob.core.windows.net/etcd-backup
```

but this says that auth is not in proper format

Comment: Please see this link on how to create a SAS using Azure Storage Resource Manager API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/listservicesas.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for a quick response . Actually in this how do i authenticate. I want to only use curl command so i am not sure how to user_impersonation the service principal in this

Comment: You will need to get a bearer token before you can call Azure Storage Resource Manager API. Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-curl. HTH.

Comment: This link will also help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage-sas#get-a-sas-credential-from-azure-resource-manager-to-make-storage-calls

Comment: @GauravMantriI am not able to understand how to generate a bearer token from SP?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the two links:

1. [Get an access token and use it to call Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage#get-an-access-token-and-use-it-to-call-azure-storage)
2. [Get a SAS credential from Azure Resource Manager to make storage calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage-sas#get-a-sas-credential-from-azure-resource-manager-to-make-storage-calls)

Code sample:

```
# get access token
response=$(curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2F' -H Metadata:true -s)
access_token=$(echo $response | python -c 'import sys, json; print (json.load(sys.stdin)["access_token"])')
echo The managed identities for Azure resources access token is $access_token

# get the SAS token with access token
curl https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>/listServiceSas/?api-version=2017-06-01 -X POST -d "{\"canonicalizedResource\":\"/blob/<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>/<CONTAINER NAME>\",\"signedResource\":\"c\",\"signedPermission\":\"rcw\",\"signedProtocol\":\"https\",\"signedExpiry\":\"<EXPIRATION TIME>\"}" -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
```

Be sure to replace the `<SUBSCRIPTION ID>`, `<RESOURCE GROUP>`, `<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>`, `<CONTAINER NAME>`, and `<EXPIRATION TIME>` parameter values with your own values.

Comment: i tried this but the issue is that it is not able to upload large files. When i generate a sas token manually from portal then that sas token works.

Comment: This is the error The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit. </Message><MaxLimit>67108864</MaxLimit></Error>

Comment: There's a 4-MB limit when uploading a file using the SAS url (REST API) or HTTPS PUT method. If your file is larger than 4 MB, you must break it in chunks.

Comment: And there is a sample about uploading large files: https://gist.github.com/RNHTTR/784f7851d0cf379532b4007c6032d777

Comment: When i generate a sas string like from the portal sp=racwdl&st=2021-04-09T05:54:16Z&se=2021-04-09T13:54:16Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=xxxx i get the signed version as 2020-02-10 and after generating the sas token from portal i am able to upload the file without any issues. is it something to do with sv version?

Comment: Yes, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services#requests-authorized-with-a-shared-access-signature). And there are the [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#remarks) about different service versions. If the size of file is larger than Maximum block size, you still need to break file in chunks. But the List Service SAS Rest API seems not to support setting signedVersion(sv).

Comment: Maybe you could try to add `&api-version=2020-06-12` when requesting Put Blob API. As the [example2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services#example-2) says,  the service executes the operation using `api-version`.

Comment: i think this version does not exist. I am not getting sas token when i replace with the version you mentioned